# Component paramaters not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

For some reason the parameters in my component doesn't seem to be changing. The problem can be solved if I subscribe to the observable but I feel like something else must be going wrong and I cant figure it out.

I have the template and viewModel in their own file.

Here is my view model:

```
function model(params){
    var viewModel = {};
    viewModel.foo = ko.observable();
    params.value.subscribe(function(data){
        viewModel.foo(data);
    });
    return viewModel;
}
```

Here is my template:

```
function template(){
    var template =`<div data-bind="text: foo></div>`;
    return template;
}
```

And here is where I register it.

```
ko.components.register('foo-template', {
    viewModel: { createViewModel: model },
    template: template()
});
```

Here is where I use it in the HTML. Foo would be a delcared observable in the main view model.

```
<foo-template params="value: foo"></foo-template>
```

Everything works fine if I subscribe to the `params.value` but I feel like I shouldn't need to use this.

Comment: What are you passing in to the params? Can you show where you use the component in the html

Comment: I edited my question with where I put it in the html.

Comment: It looks like the only place you're using the passed in value is in that subscription. If you want to avoid the subscription then you probably need to use "viewModel.foo = params.value". Is that what you tried before that didn't work?

Comment: Correct. If i get rid of the subscription nothing will update when I change the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to bind the data to a div. Divs do not normally support writable text and the text binding doesn't work well with them. If you replace the div in your template with a standard input text box everything seems to work as expected.

```js
ko.components.register('foo-template', {
    viewModel: { createViewModel: model },
    template: template()
});

function model(params){
    var viewModel = {};
    viewModel.foo = params.value;
    //viewModel.foo = ko.observable('internal value');
    return viewModel;
}

function template(){
    var template =`Internal foo: <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: foo"></input>`;
    return template;
}

ko.applyBindings({foo: ko.observable('test')});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <foo-template params="value: foo"></foo-template>
  <br />
  External foo: <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(foo)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm that's really weird because that's not working for me. Something else must be going on in my project. It's weird because the same thing is happening in another project.